# implementing auto form modal in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

How do i implement update of this package "https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-modals"

```
<template name="afModalTest">
    {{>autoformModals}}
    {{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Posts" operation="insert"}}
        Add a new post
    {{/afModal}}


    {{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Posts" operation="update" doc=singlePost}}
        Update post
    {{/afModal}}
</template>

Template.afModalTest.helpers({
    'singlePost':function(){
        return {
    "_id" : "e9kxyHQmfynYb9yoR",
    "title" : "Suman",
    "content" : "Software Engineer"
       }
    }
});
```

Insert is working but update is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change doc by singlePost._id?

```
{{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Posts" operation="update" doc=singlePost._id}}
```